# GMap.NET: Display my current position in Vb.Net from a C# code

Tags: c#, vb.net, google-maps, position, gmap.net

I would like to make an application in Vb.net that when I run, it displays my current position on the map using the GMap.Net library. 
I made this code (where  `map` is decalred as `GMapControl`):

```
Imports System.Device.Location
Imports GMap.NET
Imports GMap.NET.MapProviders  

Public Class Form1
    Dim watcher As GeoCoordinateWatcher = New GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.Default)

    Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        GMapProviders.GoogleMap.ApiKey = "xxxx"
        InitializeComponent()
        watcher.Start()
        If watcher.TryStart(False, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)) Then
            LocationMessage()
        Else
            MsgBox("Couldn't find Position")
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub LocationMessage()
        Dim whereat = watcher.Position.Location

        Dim lat = whereat.Latitude.ToString("0.000000")
        Dim lon = whereat.Longitude.ToString("0.000000")

        map.DragButton = MouseButtons.Left
        map.MapProvider = GMapProviders.GoogleMap
        map.Position = New PointLatLng(Convert.ToDouble(lat), Convert.ToDouble(lon))
    End Sub
End Class
```

But when I try to run it doesnt show me anything on map or it gets a System.OverflowException.
I tried to make the same code in C# and it works perfectly, here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using GMap.NET.MapProviders;
using GMap.NET;
using System.Device.Location;
using GMap.NET.WindowsForms;
using GMap.NET.WindowsForms.Markers;

namespace GMapC
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
     private GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.Default);

    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        watcher.Start();
        if (watcher.TryStart(false, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)))
        {
            LocationMessage();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Couldn't find Position");
        }
    }

    private void LocationMessage()
    {
        var whereat = watcher.Position.Location;

        var Lat = whereat.Latitude.ToString("0.000000");
        var Lon = whereat.Longitude.ToString("0.000000");

        map.DragButton = MouseButtons.Left;
        map.MapProvider = GMapProviders.GoogleMap;
        map.Position = new PointLatLng(Convert.ToDouble(Lat), Convert.ToDouble(Lon));
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GMapProviders.GoogleMap.ApiKey = @"xxxx";
        LocationMessage();
    }
  }
}
```

What's wrong in the Vb.net code?
Thank You

Comment: Did you try to debug the code?  Tell us where the code stops working.  The events may not be working properly and we can't tell by just looking at the code.

Comment: I did debug and it turns out that the code gets in the `LocationMessage()` Sub, but the value of `wherat ` is _Unknown_ and the values of `lat` and `lon` are _NaN_

Comment: See following : https://support.google.com/maps/answer/18539?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: There are some differences in your two codes that may or may not point to the difference in behavior.  Your C# code has a constructor for the form (this would be a `Sub New` in VB) which does most of the work that is done in `Form_Load` in VB.  The C# code looks more correct (e.g. `InitializeComponent` is normally only in a constructor).